# Update objects array from another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, leaflet, lodash

My **main task** is to update the markers on the map.

**Notation**:

*Markers that are displayed in real-time on the map*:

```
var markers = [
  { 'lat':10, 'lng':10, 'type':'simple'},
  { 'lat':20, 'lng':20, 'type':'simple'},
  { 'lat':40, 'lng':40, 'type':'cluster'}
]
```

*New markers which should be on the map*:

```
var newMarkers = [
  { 'lat':10, 'lng':10, 'type':'simple'},
  { 'lat':20, 'lng':20, 'type':'simple'},
  { 'lat':30, 'lng':30, 'type':'simple'},
  { 'lat':50, 'lng':50, 'type':'simple'}
]
```

Thus the problem is reduced to the **subtask** which I want to find solution:
**update the array of objects - `markers` from the another array of objects - `newMarkers`.**

Thus, need to perform the following manipulation with `markers` array:

1. Remove objects from `markers` which are not in `newMarkers` (compared by three properties: `lat`, `lng`, `type`).
2. Add objects from `newMarkers` into `markers` if not exist (compared by `lat`, `lng`). If marker exist (by two properies: `lat`, `lng`) is necessary to update it, i.e. to replace by a new marker from `newMarkers`.

My solution ineffective since it is because it is performed for a long time on large number of markers.

Updated `markers` array should look like:

```
console.log(markers)
{ 'lat':10, 'lng':10, 'type':'simple'},
{ 'lat':20, 'lng':20, 'type':'simple'},
{ 'lat':30, 'lng':30, 'type':'simple'},
{ 'lat':50, 'lng':50, 'type':'simple'}
```

Comment: what is your current solution?

Comment: do we know anything about the data? is it in any sorted order? are markers unique per pairing of lat/lng?

Comment: Your resulting array is exactly the same as `newMarkers`, and I don't see how it could ever be different - you're effectively getting rid of anything not in the newMarkers array

Comment: `markers = newMarkers`, judging on your example dataset.

Comment: @hackerrdave my solution, but it works slow on large markers count -http://pastebin.com/NnBU9Fpz

Comment: If `markers` contains `{ 'lat':10, 'lng':10, 'type':'simple'}` and `newMarkers` contains `{ 'lat':10, 'lng':10, 'type':'cluster'}` (note: same `lat` and `lng` but different `type`), then which do you want to keep?

Comment: @Booboobeaker the task is to update `markers` array that showed on the map in real-time. the object `{ 'lat':10, 'lng':10, 'type':'simple'}` in `markers` and object `{ 'lat':10, 'lng':10, 'type':'simple'}` not the same. They are identical to the fields and values, but they are created at different times, therefore two different memory object

Comment: @AndrewWillems I need to remove object `{ 'lat':10, 'lng':10, 'type':'simple'}` from `markers` and add object `{ 'lat':10, 'lng':10, 'type':'cluster'}` from `newMarkers` in `markers`.

Comment: @Booboobeaker if I perform `markers = newMarkers` due to the fact that the markers are displayed on the map markers attached to the array `markers`, it will cause the flicker on the map.

Comment: Is the following correct? The 1st element in each of `markers` and `newMarkers` are equal by value but not by reference, and that matters. Thus you want all the items from `newMarkers` in your updated list, but if an element in `newMarkers` has all the same property values as an already existing element in `markers` then you want to keep the original element from `markers`.

Comment: @AndrewWillems you are absolutely right!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just to re-state what was clarified in the comments after the question...

The 1st element in each of `markers` and `newMarkers` are equal by value but not by reference, and that matters. Thus you want all the items from `newMarkers` in your updated list, but if an element in `newMarkers` has all the same property values as an already existing element in `markers` then you want to keep the original element from `markers`.

The solution below loops through all the values in `newMarkers` and, if an element in `markers` has the same property values, the `markers` reference is used, otherwise the `newMarkers` reference is used.

```js
const markers = [
  { 'lat':10, 'lng':10, 'type':'simple'},
  { 'lat':20, 'lng':20, 'type':'simple'},
  { 'lat':40, 'lng':40, 'type':'cluster'}
];

const newMarkers = [
  { 'lat':10, 'lng':10, 'type':'simple'},
  { 'lat':20, 'lng':20, 'type':'simple'},
  { 'lat':30, 'lng':30, 'type':'simple'},
  { 'lat':50, 'lng':50, 'type':'simple'}
];

const updatedMarkers = newMarkers.map(newMarker =>
  markers.reduce((accumulator, origMarker) => (
    (
      origMarker.lat  === newMarker.lat  &&
      origMarker.lng  === newMarker.lng  &&
      origMarker.type === newMarker.type
    ) ? origMarker : accumulator
  ), newMarker)
);

markers.map((marker, idx) => {
  console.log(`Element #${idx} from markers is present: ${!!(updatedMarkers.indexOf(marker) + 1)}`);
});
newMarkers.map((marker, idx) => {
  console.log(`Element #${idx} from newMarkers is present: ${!!(updatedMarkers.indexOf(marker) + 1)}`);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding your problem correctly, you want to reflect changes in `newMarkers` in `markers` without simply replacing the reference on `markers`.

```
// remove (everything in markers that's not in newMarkers) from markers
_.pull(markers, ..._.difference(markers, newMarkers)); 
// push (everything in newMarkers that's not in markers) to markers
markers.push(..._.difference(newMarkers, markers));
```